# Without access on a taxonomy term page

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have created a taxonomy term "tags". If I use the url to access the content with that term I have the following error.

403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /drupal/tag/sport on this server.

"sport" is a taxonomy term and tag is the taxonomy.

Even if I am admin or anonymous user.

Answer (score 0):

around the top of your .htaccess file you have

```
# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)(|~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig\.save)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
```

just remove 'Tag', new code should look like this

```
# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)(|~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Template)$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig\.save)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
```

you can replace this lines with new one that I provided above...

Comment: I did it. I delete the "tag" from te file and clear cache but I have the same message as before